# DC-AC converter?

Tags: circuit-analysis, circuit-design, power-electronics, ecg

[image]

Source:https://digital.wpi.edu/downloads/ns064789m?locale=zh
page:15
[image]

Could someone tell me what component is this? ADC as a switch?! I am trying to build the 12 lead ECG circuit with Schematic symbols in Proteus 8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an [SPDT switch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Switch#Contact_terminology) used to remove (or integrate-out) DC offset voltages from the output of the INA321 when placed in the position shown. In the other position it just connects pin 5 (the instrumentation amplifier's reference pin) to 0 volts thus, leaving the DC output unaffected.